# Approximate delta distribution with indicator function

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Is it true that

$$\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]} f(t)g(s)2^m\sum_{\substack{i=0}}^{2^{m}-1}\mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{i}{2^m},\frac{i+1}{2^m}
\right]}(t)\mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{i}{2^m},\frac{i+1}{2^m}
\right]}(s)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}s\xrightarrow{m\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}f(t)g(t)\mathrm{d}t$$
holds, where $f,g$ are square-integrable?

This comes from trying to find a representation for time white noise.

I feel like it should because as $m$ goes to infinity, the indicator functions should `force' $s$ and $t$ to become equal and the length of that interval would be $\frac{1}{2^m}$.

This resembles the definition of the delta distribution: if we were to substitute the part of the integrand which isn't $f(t)g(s)$ by $\delta(t-s)$, we would get $\int_{[0,1]}f(t)g(t)\mathrm{d}t$.

Any hints/suggestions on how can I prove this rigorously (if it even holds)?

EDIT: some details for where this comes from:

Let's start with this representation for time white noise:
$$\xi(t)=\lim_{m\to\infty}2^{\frac{m}{2}}\sum_{i=0}^{2^m-1}X_{i,m}\mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{i}{2^m},\frac{i+1}{2^m}
\right]}(t),$$
where the $X_{i,m}$ are i.i.d. standard normal random variables.
We need to show that it satisfies the properties to be time white noise, that is to say:
$$\mathbb{E}[\xi(f)\xi(g)]=\langle f,g\rangle.$$
The left hand side equals (using the independence of the random variables considered)
\begin{align*}&\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^1\xi(t)f(t)\mathrm{d}t\int_0^1\xi(t)g(t)\mathrm{d}t\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^1\xi(t)f(t)\mathrm{d}t\right]\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^1\xi(t)g(t)\mathrm{d}t\right]\\
&=\int_0^1\mathbb{E}\left[\xi(t)\right]f(t)\mathrm{d}t\int_0^1\mathbb{E}\left[\xi(t)\right]g(t)\mathrm{d}t\mbox{      (still not sure how I can justify this)}\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(t)g(s)\mathbb{E}\left[\xi(s)\xi(t)\right]\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}s\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(t)g(s)\mathbb{E}\left[\lim_{\substack{m\to\infty\\n\to\infty}}2^{\frac{m}{2}+\frac{n}{2}}\sum_{\substack{i=0\\j=0}}^{\substack{2^{m}-1\\2^n-1}}X_{i,m}X_{j,n}\mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{i}{2^m},\frac{i+1}{2^m}
\right]}(t)\mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{j}{2^n},\frac{j+1}{2^n}
\right]}(t)\right]\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}s\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(t)g(s)\lim_{\substack{m\to\infty\\n\to\infty}}2^{\frac{m}{2}+\frac{n}{2}}\sum_{\substack{i=0\\j=0}}^{\substack{2^{m}-1\\2^n-1}}\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i,m}X_{j,n}\right]\mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{i}{2^m},\frac{i+1}{2^m}
\right]}(t)\mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{j}{2^n},\frac{j+1}{2^n}
\right]}(t)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}s\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(t)g(s)\lim_{\substack{m\to\infty}}2^{m}\sum_{\substack{i=0}}^{\substack{2^{m}-1}}\mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{i}{2^m},\frac{i+1}{2^m}
\right]}(t)\mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{i}{2^m},\frac{i+1}{2^m}
\right]}(s)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}s.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $I_{m,i} = [\frac{i}{2^m},\frac{i+1}{2^m}]$ and introduce the averaging operator $A_m : L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$ given by

$$ (A_m f)(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{2^m-1} \left( 2^m \int_{I_{m,i}} f(s) \, \mathrm{d}s \right) \mathbf{1}_{I_{m,i}}(t). $$

We claim that $A_m$ is a bounded operator on $L^2([0,1])$. Indeed, this follows from the following computation

\begin{align*}
\|A_m f(t)\|_{L^2}^2
&= \int_{0}^{1} |A_m f(t)|^2 \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{i=0}^{2^m-1} \left( 2^m \int_{I_{m,i}} |f(s)| \, \mathrm{d}s \right)^2 \mathbf{1}_{I_{m,i}}(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{2^m-1} 2^m \left( \int_{I_{m,i}} |f(s)| \, \mathrm{d}s \right)^2  \\
&\stackrel{\text{C-S}}{\leq} \sum_{i=0}^{2^m-1} \int_{I_{m,i}} |f(s)|^2 \, \mathrm{d}s
= \|f\|_{L^2}^2.
\end{align*}

Notice that this operator is related to the quantity of interest by the following identity:

$$ \int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]} f(t)g(s) 2^m \sum_{i=1}^{2^m-1}\mathbf{1}_{I_{m,i}}(t)\mathbf{1}_{I_{m,i}}(s) \, \mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}s
= ( A_m f, g )_{L^2}
= ( f, A_m g )_{L^2} $$

Next, if $f$ is continuous then it is easy to prove that $A_m f \to f$ in $L^{\infty}$ and hence in $L^2$. Thus for any $f, g \in L^2([0,1])$ and for any $\tilde{g} \in C([0,1])$, we have

\begin{align*}
|(f, A_m g)_{L^2} - (f, g)_{L^2}|
&\leq \|f\|_{L^2} \| A_m g - g\|_{L^2} \\
&\leq \|f\|_{L^2} \left( \| A_m(g - \tilde{g}) \|_{L^2} + \| A_m \tilde{g} - \tilde{g} \|_{L^2} + \| \tilde{g} - g \|_{L^2} \right) \\
&\leq \|f\|_{L^2} \left( 2 \| g - \tilde{g} \|_{L^2} + \| A_m \tilde{g} - \tilde{g} \|_{L^2} \right).
\end{align*}

Taking limsup as $m\to\infty$, since $A_m \tilde{g} \to \tilde{g}$ in $L^2$, we have

$$ \limsup_{m\to\infty} |(f, A_m g)_{L^2} - (f, g)_{L^2}| \leq 2 \|f\|_{L^2} \| g - \tilde{g} \|_{L^2}. $$

Then taking $\tilde{g} \to g$ in $L^2$ proves the desired conclusion:

$$ \lim_{m\to\infty} (f, A_m g)_{L^2} = (f, g)_{L^2}. $$

---

*Remark.* This result itself tells that $A_m \to I$ in the [weak operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_operator_topology). On the other hand, a slight modification of the proof actually tells that $A_m \to I$ in the [strong operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_operator_topology):

$$ \forall g \in L^2([0,1]) \ : \qquad A_m g \to g \quad \text{in } L^2. $$

I am not sure if $A_m \to I$ in the operator-norm topology.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Sangchul Lee! I think there might be a couple of typos, so I've just tried correcting them

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt, That is not a typo. You can try to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to check that $$\left(\int_{I_{m,i}} |f(x)|\,dx\right)^2 \leq \left(\int_{I_{m,i}} |f(x)|^2 \,dx\right)\left(\int_{I_{m,i}} 1\,dx\right) = \frac{1}{2^m}\int_{I_{m,i}} |f(x)|^2\,dx.$$

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry about that, and thanks for the follow-up explanation!

Comment: Although in the first inequality, the left bracket should have been placed before the summation operator, right?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt, No worries :) And as for that part, I might have been too hasty about my explanation. Here I used the fact that $$ \mathbf{1}_{I_{m,i}} \mathbf{1}_{I_{m,j}} = \begin{cases} \mathbf{1}_{I_{m,i}}, & \text{if } i = j \\ 0, & \text{if } i \neq j \end{cases} \quad \text{a.e.} $$ to simply the square of the sum. This allows to write $$ \left( \sum_{i=0}^{2^m-1} c_i \mathbf{1}_{I_{m,i}} \right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{2^m-1} c_i^2 \mathbf{1}_{I_{m,i}} \quad \text{a.e.} $$ for any $c_0, \cdots, c_{2^m-1}$.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt, Or, perhaps a better explanation is that we have $$ \sum_{i=0}^{2^m-1} c_i \mathbf{1}_{m,i}(t) = c_j \quad \text{for a.e. } t \in I_{m,j}, $$ that is, for a.e. $t \in [0, 1]$ exactly one term in the sum survives. So this summation is just a convenient substitute of the piecewise definition. Consequently, for any continuous function $\varphi$ we still have $$ \varphi\left( \sum_{i=0}^{2^m-1} c_i \mathbf{1}_{m,i}(t) \right) = \sum_{i=0}^{2^m-1} \varphi(c_i) \mathbf{1}_{m,i}(t) \quad \text{a.e.} $$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63391/discussion-between-man-in-green-shirt-and-sangchul-lee).

Comment: sorry, one more question: why do you use $\limsup$? Seeing as $L^2[0,1]$ is complete, don't we know that the limit exists and hence is equal to the $\limsup$?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt, Of course the limit exists, but this does not come free and it is something we have to show as part of our proof. (And this has nothing to do with completeness.) $\limsup$ is a convenient substitute in this regard.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - once we've shown that $A_mf\xrightarrow{m\to\infty}f$ in $L^{\infty}[0,1]$, doesn't that show that the limit exists?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt, Although I did not emphasize enough, I clarified in my proof that the convergence in your question holds *a priori* for continuous function $f$. In fact, there is no way this $L^{\infty}$ convergence extends to all $f \in L^2$ since the averaging operator $A_m$ smooths out $f$.

Comment: @Sanghchul Lee sorry, I still don't get it. You're assuming $\tilde{g}$ to be continuous, so if convergence holds a priori, then why do you need to take $\limsup_{m\to\infty}$ of $A_m\tilde{g}$?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt, I am taking limsup as $m\to\infty$ to the quantity $|(f, A_m g)_{L^2} - (f, g)_{L^2}|$. We want to show that this converges to $0$ but at this point we do not know if this is true. On the other hand, the quantity $\| A_m \tilde{g} - \tilde{g} \|_{L^2}$ in my upper bound is known to converge to $0$ as $m\to\infty$, allowing us to kill this term in the limit.

Comment: got it, thank you for answering all my follow-up questions